# Safeguard tennis trainers against worn heels

Tags: shoes, sports

I play a lot of hardcourt tennis.

I'm getting through one pair of (K-swiss) trainers every six months or less, because the lining on the inside of the heel wears out.

It's unusual. Usually the sole is the first to go. For these shoes however the sole is surprisingly resilient.

It's frustrating, because it's an expensive shoe, it takes weeks to wear in and become comfortable, and apart from this the shoe is in
 excellent condition and could last -- who knows -- maybe a couple of years?

There isn't much choice for hardcourt tennis shoe, and it's been hard work finding one that fits my foot, so when I do replace them it will be with the same model.

Is there some hack that will let me extend the lifetime for the next pair I buy?

Obviously some piece of material, but I can't think of a good choice or a good way to attach it.

I don't think I can sew through a trainer.

Comment: I wonder if you can solve this via socks. Do you wear socks with these trainers? If not, you certainly should. If you do, perhaps you can sew something onto the heel of the sock.

Comment: Are standard shoe inserts too thick? You might glue them in place with a flexible fabric cement.

Comment: Woops, I should have mentioned, it's the back of the heel, not the bottom, so inserts won't cut it. And yes, I do wear socks -- never understood how some people don't!

Comment: How tight do you tie them? If it's too loose and your heel slips around a lot inside the shoe, this might speed up the wear.

Comment: +1 for a well-asked question. I don't think there's much you can do without increasing the weight of the trainers, in which case you might as well just buy running shoes that have thicker soles to begin with....but let's see what turns up. I've been surprised by LH answers before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A good option would be to invest in some gel type in soles. They will protect your heels, and they are cheaper to replace than a pair of good trainers.

you can pick them up from shoe shops, ebay, or your local pharmacy. It may also be worth getting your worn out trainers repaired at your local cobbler. It costs very little, and they can give professional advice.

Answer (score 0):

Coat the inside of the heal with a tool dip or with shoe goo.  It will put an extra layer of material there and can be reapplied as you wear it out.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, but I can imagine it being uncomfortable, because both products get pretty hard. Maybe try something durable but more soft.